# store a button id in php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made changes in my code as suggested. Here's my updated code:

```
<form  action="" method="POST">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="navbtnplace" value="<?=$country?>">
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="navbtnplace" value="<?=$state?>">
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="navbtnplace" value="<?=$city?>">
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="navbtnplace" value="<?=$user_name?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['navbtnplace'])) {
                    echo  $_POST['navbtnplace'];

                }
                ?>
```

But it refreshes the page as well. How can I get the button value without page refresh?

Comment: Could you explain what *extract* is doing? Does it `echo` something, does it need access to the HTML document (in that case you should not be doing this in PHP), does it retrieve some data that should be output in the browser?

Comment: PHP runs on the server and delivers html to the user's browser. When they click in the browser, the PHP has already run. The JavaScript ajax request is the route go, because it makes another request to the server whereby you can run more PHP.

Answer (score 1):

PHP not capable to catch html's id as form data. If you want catch the html's id and insert it to variable you must do a simple trick, insert button's value same as its id. So, your buttons should be like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="a" name="idVal" value="a" class"navbtnplace">
    <input type="submit" id="b" name="idVal" value="b" class"navbtnplace">
    <input type="submit" id="c" name="idVal" value="c" class"navbtnplace">
    <input type="submit" id="d" name="idVal" value="d" class"navbtnplace">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['idVal'])) {
    ext($_REQUEST['idVal']);
}

function ext($id) {
   echo $id;
}
```

Please review your code at switch case process and you should not create function with has same name with native php function.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only take the form data - whatever is in `value` attribute So, you can't get the `id` value in PHP code.
If you want to check which button is pressed, You can only check it using `value` attribute.

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <!-- other form fields -->
            <input type="button" id="a" name="idVal" value="a" class"navbtnplace">
            <input type="button" id="b" name="idVal" value="b" class"navbtnplace">
            <input type="button" id="c" name="idVal" value="c" class"navbtnplace">
            <input type="button" id="d" name="idVal" value="d" class"navbtnplace">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?PHP
    echo $_POST['idVal'];
?>
```

**NOTE:** If you send an AJAX request to store the value and then submit the form (separately), you will lose the first value because, those two are the independent requests. But, SESSION and COOKIE will work in this scenario. once, a value is saved in session via AJAX or the normal form submission, It'll be saved Globally and you can access the saved values after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

No need of switch just call `extact()` funtion with value sent by form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['idVal'])) {
    $navBtnVal = $_REQUEST['idVal'];
    extract($navBtnVal);
}

function extract($id) {
    //some event
}
?>

<!-- Change action attribute to some other page if you want to send data to somewhere else.  -->
<!-- You also missed equal operator(=) in class -->
<!-- Give an extra attribute value and put its value as like id as below. Because php will receive your value attribute's data-->
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="button" id="a" name="idVal" value="a" class="navbtnplace" />
    <input type="button" id="b" name="idVal" value="b" class="navbtnplace" />
    <input type="button" id="c" name="idVal" value="c" class="navbtnplace" />
    <input type="button" id="d" name="idVal" value="d" class="navbtnplace" />
</form>
```